# serverless-offline-sqs : I get botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3, fastapi, amazon-sqs

I am working on an application that uses AWS SQS. For testing functionality locally I am trying to use serverless-offline-sqs plugin however I am unable to move past the following error:

```
  File "/Users/randomName/project/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 418, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError()
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Here is how I am using the boto3 library and the sqs client:

```
import boto3
sqs_boto_client = boto3.client('sqs', region_name='ap-south-1')


def send_message(queue_url, record, delay_seconds=0):
    print('record to enter in sqs', record)
    message = json.dumps(record, default=custom_encoder)
    sqs_boto_client.send_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url, MessageBody=message, DelaySeconds=delay_seconds)
    return True
```

I tried the following but it doesnt seem to work:

Set the following keys in environment section of serverless.yml:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ""
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ""
```

in my settings file:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
```

And while creating the sqs client:

```
sqs_boto_client = boto3.client('sqs', region_name='ap-south-1', aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

Any suggestions on what to do to handle this issue would be great!

Comment: Can you post the full contents of `serverless.yml`?